# Conversion hex to BigInt node red

Tags: javascript, node-red

I imported [BigInter.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) to the functionGlobalContext of node-red, however when I use `var maximumByte = BigInt("FF", 16);` (for bigInt the function is not known) it  gives the following error `SyntaxError: Cannot convert FF to a BigInt` How can this be solved?

Comment: Edit the question to show the whole function,

Comment: It appeared that the library was overwritten by the standard library, which was included in a newer version

Comment: Not sure about BitInter.js, but if you try using BigInt type just add "0x" prefix before hex string. For example:
const hex = '102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F000';
const base = 10;
const bn = BigInt('0x' + hex);
// ↪ 21434780083170533584713300915655864320n
bn.toString(base);
// ↪ "21434780083170533584713300915655864320"